# Error :Submitting the app to Firefox Market Place

Tags: html, web-applications, vs-web-application-project, firefox-os

I am trying to submit a new app into the firefox marketplace but I don`t know why it is showing the below error..

**Your app failed validation with 1 error.
    Error extracting manifest from zip file.**

I cannot install it through server to b2g mobile too as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Packaged_apps).. as it is saying "Download Failed in the mobile.

Here`s my manifest file

```
{ "name": "Check Location", "description": "This app allows you to check your Location!", "launch_path": "/app.html", "developer": { "name": "RB", "url": "http://nothing.me" }, "icons": { "16": "/img/icon16.png", "32": "/img/icon32.png", "48": "/img/icon48.png", "64": "/img/icon64.png", "128": "/img/icon128.png" }, "default_locale": "en",  "permissions": { "geolocation": {
            "description" : "Marking out user location"
        } } }
```

Here`s package.manifest

```
{ "name": "Check Location", "description": "This app allows you to check your Location!", "launch_path": "/app.html", "developer": { "name": "RB", "url": "http://nothing.me" }, "icons": { "16": "/img/icon16.png", "32": "/img/icon32.png", "48": "/img/icon48.png", "64": "/img/icon64.png", "128": "/img/icon128.png" }, "default_locale": "en",  "permissions": { "geolocation": {
            "description" : "Marking out user location"
        } } }
```

I have done pasting Index.html, css and js folder into the package folder and zipped it as they have mentioned. But when I upload the zip file into the market place it is showing the error.. Please help me with this.. Check out the complete code [Here](https://github.com/ashwinyuvi12/SampleFOSApp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error simply denotes that system cannot find manifest.webapp from your zip file.
https://github.com/mozilla/zamboni/blob/master/mkt/developers/forms.py#L512

You should make sure manifest.webapp is in root directory of your .zip file.

One possible mistake might be doing like below:

```
zip -r foo.zip foo/*
```

This will create a zip file whose root only contains foo folder, thus the submission system cannot find your manifest.

You should instead do:

```
cd foo 
zip -r foo.zip *
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Exactly bro!! But I am using windows system.. I am zipping the file using the winrar.. Pls check this.. These are all the files, I am putting inside the folder and zipping it... github.com/ashwinyuvi12/SampleFOSApp

Comment: The Mainifest.webapp file is exactly where the app.html is. It`s working when I access it from my browser.. But still I cannot able to upload.. Even I`ve checked downloading Boiler plate app https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App, it`s not working. I`ve zipped it directly and uploaded it.. It`s been 2 days I am struggling with it.. :(

Comment: I'm not sure about winrar, but what I'm saying is that, you shouldn't zip the folder itself. If you do, generated zip contain the folder in which manifest.webapp exist (not in the root). Instead, you should choose all files in your project directory and zip it (Again, I'm not sure how you can do this by winrar :P)
Your project structure seems fine, so the problem may be around how you zip it.

Comment: Yayyyy!! Thank u very much.. It`s now detecting my Manifest file.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not zip the main folder of the app directly.if you saved your app content in a main folder then open folder select all the contents and then select compress or Zip option.Submit it to the Marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the zip file it is hard to say what exactly is wrong. Is this a packaged or hosted app? For hosted apps, you do not need to zip the app and can just pass the URL of you manifest to the validator. Of course, you have to first upload the app to it's unique domain.

There is a mailing list for webapp developers (dev-webapps) and one to contact app reviewers (app-reviewers). I would try dev-webapps since you have not submitter your app for review yet. But both of those channels are pretty responsive.

There are also a number of useful irc channels on `irc.mozilla.org` that you could use:

- `#openwebapps` would probably be best place to ask about your issue
- `#marketplace` also another good place to ask about marketplace issues
- `#app-reviewers` any question about the review process

I hope that helps a bit. If you insist on getting an answer here, please provide the information I asked and a link to the zip file so I can take a look. Cheers!

Comment: Thank u for the reply!! It`s a packaged app. My 'package' folder has, A CSS folder in which I have the css file named app.css and JS file named app.js and a manifest file called Manifest.webapp.. Everything seeming to be perfect! Try with github Repository to upload the complete folder!!

Comment: Hi Bro!! Pls check this out!! Here`s the content inside the zip folder | https://github.com/ashwinyuvi12/SampleFOSApp

Comment: looks like Kazuki gave a great answer to your question above. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message 2 days ago. I was confused, because it talked about manifest instead of manifest.webapp as usually documented as being required.
Uncertain about my understanding I copied my manifest.webapp to manifest and included it to my Zip. 
Believe it or not, the Zip was accepted now. 
Later I tried to verify the issue and removed the webapp, but now the Zip was still accepted as it should have been from the beginning.

 Maybe, if nothing else helps you might give it a try.

Comment: manifest.webapp to manifest Means? You mean I`ve to change manifest.webapp to manifest?

Comment: Here`s the file.. Kindly let me know what changes I need to make.. github.com/ashwinyuvi12/SampleFOSApp